# ListPreference with possibility to enter own option in Android

Tags: android, android-preferences

I have ListPreferences in properties.xml and standart Preferences Acitvity. All possible options of that property are in those xml. It list of predefined URLs.

ButI want to provide user possibility to enter it's own value in this preference his own URL.

How can I do that?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would add CheckBoxPreference "Use custom URL" and two dependable preferences - ListPreference "Common urls" and EditTextPreference "Custom url"